# How to avoid null field errors in spock for Grails domain mock

Tags: grails, spock

Using grails 2.2.0 given this simple Domain

```
class Order {
    static mapping = {table "ticket_order"}

    String foo
}
```

And associated spock test

```
@TestFor(Order)
class OrderSpec extends Specification {
def "sensible constraints for order class"() {
    setup:
      mockForConstraintsTests(Order)

      when:
      def order = new Order(
        foo : foo
      )
      order.validate()

      then:
        !order.errors.hasFieldErrors("foo")

      where:
        foo = "bar"

}
}
```

I get this output

```
grails> test-app unit: Order -echoOut
| Running 1 spock test... 1 of 1
--Output from sensible constraints for order class--
| Failure:  sensible constraints for order class(uk.co.seoss.presscm.OrderSpec)
|  Condition not satisfied:

!order.errors.hasFieldErrors("foo")
||     |      |
||     |      true
||     org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockErrors: 1 errors
||     Field error in object 'uk.co.seoss.presscm.Order' on field 'foo': rejected value [null];
```

Could someone please explain why I'm getting that null, have I not set the property correctly? I've tried a few simpler formulations of this with no joy. It works fine in a standard unit test.

Comment: Have you tried with a plain JUnit test? My best guess is that the problem isn't related to Spock.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your mixing the data-driven and interaction based testing styles. 
The where block is mentioned only in the context of data-driven, and the when/then combo in the context of interaction testing.

Try put def foo = "bar" at the top of the test.

Comment: `when-then` can be used for any test (not just interaction-based), and it works fine together with `where`.